# License Edition INVALID is not valid for JW Player Android SDK

Tags: android, jwplayer, android-video-player, video-player, license-key

I've been trying to implement https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-android-demo but constantly its declaring my license as invalid. I've added license in manifest as well and I've a trial account in jwplayer.

Do I need to have licensed sdk for implementing it in android? Can anyone help?

Comment: Which version of JW player are you using? JW8 requires a new key (your exising JW6/JW7 ones will not work with JW8), and you'll not be able to get this new JW8 key unless you subscribe to a paid edition of the player.

Comment: I'm using license of jw8. i've subscribed to paid edition but currently on free trial period.Can it be the reason?
I'm a new jw user btw @jherrieven

Answer (score 0):

A while after you asked, but on the left menu you should see the option "Players", then "Download and Keys", there will be the keys for each platform. (as on September 2019)